# win7 Whats the best way of clearing permissions?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, permissions

I have a Win7 PC with two hard drives. The primary is too small, and so I want to reload Win7 on the bigger drive, after making it the primary.

My problem is that when I have tried this in the past, the existing files and folders keep their original permissions, with some unknown SSID - the original installation and users which is no longer around. Then I keep getting permission errors.

The only way I've figured to avoid this previously, is to transfer all the data elsewhere, a separate drive, and treat this bigger drive as new: Format and go for it.

Is there another way?

Comment: Most of the permission problems people have with NTFS is file ownership. You can take ownership of a folder and include all subfolders and files therein.

Answer (score 1):

To change the ownership of your files and folders you can follow this article:
http://www.faqforge.com/windows/take-ownership-of-a-file-or-folder-by-command-in-windows/

I think you have to have admin's right though! I thing the best way to do it is to right-click on `cmd` and `Run as administrator`!

> To start off, you need an elevated command prompt which is simply a
>   command prompt opened as administrator. In Windows 8 you can open that
>   by right-clicking the bottom left corner of the screen and selecting
>   Command Prompt (Admin). In Windows 7 and previous, search the main
>   menu for cmd, right-click it and select Open as administrator.
>
> You need two commands now: one to actually take ownership of the file
>   or folder and one to grant yourself access rights. These are the two
>   commands you will want to use:
>
> For folders, use:
>
> ```
> takeown /f folder_name /r /d y
> icacls folder_name /grant username_or_usergroup:F /t /q
> ```
>
> For files, use:
>
> ```
> takeown /f file_name /d y
> icacls file_name /grant username_or_usergroup:F /q
> ```
>
> The commands basically only differ in a few switches that make the
>   folder procession run recursively. If you want to edit only one folder
>   instead of the whole recursive lot, remove the /r and /t switches from
>   the commands. For more info on the commands, simply enter takeown /?
>   or icacls /? into the command prompt.
>
> If I wanted to take control of my Program Files folder, I'd need to
>   enter the following:
>
> ```
> takeown /f "C:\Program Files" /r /d y
> icacls "C:\Program Files" /grant christian:F /t /q
> ```

Comment: Ownership is not a problem....  I didn't think it was that simple.

Comment: If you have the files already, you can try on them!